# How to create autogenerate ID in angular?

Tags: angularjs

> Want to create autogenerate code in angular inputbox on refresh page
>   like rand(function) in php. Im using this script for this. But problem
>   is its vanished on page refresh not working properly.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function randString(x){
    var s = "OL-";
    while(s.length<x&&x>0){
        var r = Math.random();
        s+= (r<0.1?Math.floor(r*100):String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(r*26) + (r>0.5?97:65)));
    }
    return s;
}
document.getElementById("referal_code").value = randString(10);
</script>

<input required type='text' class='span2' id='referal_code' ng-model='empInfo.referal_code'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function getNewID() {
            try {
                var myDate = new Date();
                var varID = myDate.getHours() + "" + myDate.getMinutes() + "" + myDate.getSeconds() + "" + myDate.getMilliseconds();
                if (varID.Length > 15) {
                    varID = varID.substr(0, 15);
                }
                return varID;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }

        function randString(x){
            var s = getNewID();
            return s;
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("referal_code").value = randString(10);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input required type='text' class='span2' id='referal_code' ng-model='empInfo.referal_code'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it comes on page load n within seconds disappers

Comment: Run here it  is not disappering,

Answer (score 0):

For any attribute in angular world you can use interpolation like this:

```
<input id="{{randString(10)}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a certain value as id and not get lost after refresh you have to save it on some web storage (localstorage, sessionstorage).

e.g. :

```
function randString(x){
 // ... your function's logic

 //Save it in localStorage before returning it
 localStorage.inputId = s;

 return s;
}

document.getElementById("referal_code").value = localStorage.inputId || randString(10)
```